# Understanding Code block of helper.php in mod_menu of Joomla 3.x

Tags: joomla3.0, joomla3.2

I'm trying to understand the helper.php file in the mod_menu folder of Joomla 3.x. The section of code which I am looking it is where we come across the first isset call to check the values of our new introduced elements

In particular Im trying to figure out how $item->shallower is able to calculate the depth of the menu structure which differentiates from the deeper, It allows us to create lists in list elements via the default output template for this particular module.

```
    // add these elements to each item

    $item->deeper     = false;
    $item->shallower  = false;
    $item->level_diff = 0;

if (isset($items[$lastitem])) {

    $items[$lastitem]->deeper     = ($item->level > $items[$lastitem]->level);
    $items[$lastitem]->shallower  = ($item->level < $items[$lastitem]->level);
    $items[$lastitem]->level_diff = ($items[$lastitem]->level - $item->level);

    var_dump($items[$lastitem]->shallower);//(bool)true or false
    var_dump($item->level);//string
    var_dump($items[$lastitem]->level);//string
    }
```

I am just struggling to get my head round this piece of code, more so both $item->deeper and $item->level seem to working as they should, but I have no understanding of what $lastitem]->shallower is doing. Any explanation would be most helpful.

regards

w9914420

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is `$lastitem`, which is the index of the previous item created; it is set right after the code you pasted:

```
$lastitem     = $i;
```

where $i is the key in the foreach loop above that iterates through all $items with the variable $item.

Thus, on the next iteration, `$items[$lastitem]` is the previous item created.

In order to determine if an item has subitems, it's sufficient to compare the current and previous elements levels.  This is an efficient way to achieve this, as only one iteration through all the items is necessary to build the data structure and integrate the deeper/shallower fields.

Shallower is the opposite of deeper:

```
+ item
+-- item // this is deeper;
+-- item
+-- item
+ item   // this is shallower;
+ item
```

Comment: Hi Riccardo,Sorry for the late response, I had to go away and do some vigorous testing. I understand what you mean now, since $lastitem references the last iteration created in the loop (which is refered to earlier in the code). I understand now what the value of shallower is and why it is important. without going off topic is this working by evaluating values from the created items and then using these values as identifies to denote the state of the element within the object $items[$lastitems] which in itself seems to be collection of objects :-S

Comment: I added a short explanation at the top, I hope it helps explain better. $items is indeed the collection of all menu items.

Comment: Hi @riccardozorn thanks again for your insight, I went away and had a look into foreach to see exactly what it was doing, it does not behave how I originally thought ;). Cheers

Comment: Hello @riccardozorn my last question is that if statement (isset($items[$lastitem])) is called again after it as already been set in the Helper file. Again I assume that since the properties: deeper, shallower & level_diff have previously been set to establish the basic level. This if statement allows us to set the level for which a menu will render in mod_menu, can I safely assume that it's recall will allow you to set the start level and therefore re-write these properties? - thanks again.

Comment: No its intention is to prevent notices when $lastitem is not assigned i.e. on the first round.

Comment: Ok, I thought that it would be assigned since the array is broken down into items with the additional properties. I see that both the foreach and last if statement would execute at the same time - wow - so in essence this is a safeguard, which uses the $start as a base marker? Before iteration?

Comment: Yes, both parts execute on every loop iteration, except the first iteration where the if condition fails since there is no $lastitem yet.

Comment: Hi @riccardozorn, thanks again for your time and explanation I really appreciate it. I have a better understanding of what is happening, I must admit that the whole process of creating those additional properties is quite complicated in my mind. Just out of interest I wonder If I could ask in a hypothetical way, if you think that this is the best way of doing this? I was thinking of exploring this further for my own interests ;)

Comment: Yes I think this is definitely the best generic approach, it's very simple and "cost effective" as it only performs one iteration.  Of course if you have few menu items, it won't make a measurable difference to iterate over the list 15 times; if you have 10,000 then it could be an issue.